# Dough nut pie chart in react native android

Tags: react-native

I want to display a doughnut pie chart something like the following:

[image: Dough nut pie chart]

[react-native-chart](https://github.com/tomauty/react-native-chart) does not work for android while other solutions like [react-native-chart-android](https://github.com/hongyin163/react-native-chart-android) don't work out of the box and require a little bit of setup to achieve this.Can someone suggest me the easiest way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

We have just used:

https://github.com/mskec/react-native-mp-android-chart

For a commercial react-native product (to make pie charts also), it is probably the most up-to-date android library for graphing and can easily be modified if needed. Highly recommend.